# Dart WebUI html data values

Tags: html, dart, dart-webui

I am having some issues with dart's web ui package.

First of all, i see that web ui is not interpreting html tags.
Is it not possible to use, for example `<br />` tags, to inject html code inside div or span elements in html?

EDIT:

I have this in my html doc:

```
<span>{{dataValue}}</span>
```

This in my dart file:

```
String dataValue = "This is an example <br /> using line breaks";
```

By "inject" in ment putting `dataValue` string inside its placeholder(`{{dataValue}}`) in html document.
My question is can i somehow interpret this string as html? Now it is displaying `<br />` tags as regular text, and not interpreting it as a html linebreak.

Comment: I don't understand the question :( You can write any HTML code in `<template>` tag. What do you mean 'inject HTML code' ?

Comment: Wow, youre fast Jasper :) I edited my initial question, hope it is more clear now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is working as intended. It would be a security problem if arbitrary HTML code could be injected as a string in this way.

You can, however, add a line break to your string with `\n`, which will be visible on your page.

Or you can use the Dart HTML libraries to add elements where you want them.

For example:

```
<span id="mySpan"></span>
```

```dart
import 'dart:html';

var span = query('#mySpan');
span.append(new Text('first half of my text'));
span.append(new BrElement());
span.append(new Text('second half of my text'));
```

Comment: Or if your trust the content, you can write `{{ new SafeHtml.unsafe(dataValue) }}`.